# why does using persian characters not worked for onchange event in javascript

Tags: textbox, onchange

why javascript onchange not triggered for textbox when characters are in persian? but it triggers when characters are in english.
here are the codes:

```
<input type="text" onchange="field_changed(this,<?php echo $row['id']; ?>);">
javascript codes :
function field_changed(nvalue,fid){
           alert("hello");
}
```